# BadCafe as a git object short hash

Tags: python, git

as I was reading the Git Internals in the Pro Git book, I decided to see what objects I need to create to have the short hash say something funny. To do this, I have written the following code:

```
messages = ['badcafe','deaddad','badbeef','feedbac']
possible_letters = string.ascii_lowercase + string.ascii_uppercase + ' '

def getHash(data):
    return hashlib.sha1(str("blob " + str(len(data)) + "\0" + data).encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()

def populate(n):
    for data in product(possible_letters, repeat=n):
        s = getHash(''.join(data))[0:7]
        if s in messages:
            print(s,data)
```

Unfortunately, this is too slow for n > 4. For smaller n, it only finds badcafe. Is there any way to speed this up?

Answer (score 1):

That's a brute force search of hashes for a particular prefix, meaning it's complexity is \$O(2^n)\$, where \$n\$ is the number of bits in the prefix. In your case that's \$2^{28}\$.

You can't make it faster in terms of complexity or the hash would be broken, but you can increase the constant factor.

---

Using cProfile I see that out of 30 seconds of runtime the worst offenders are:

```
8042221   10.763    0.000   24.243    0.000 tmp.py:10(getHash)
      5    5.138    1.028   30.701    6.140 tmp.py:13(populate)
8042222    3.805    0.000    3.805    0.000 {_hashlib.openssl_sha1}
8042221    5.143    0.000    5.143    0.000 {method 'encode' of 'str' objects}
8042221    3.876    0.000    3.876    0.000 {method 'hexdigest' of '_hashlib.HASH' objects}
8042221    1.320    0.000    1.320    0.000 {method 'join' of 'str' objects}
```

The actual hashing is done in `hexdigest` and OpenSSL. Those pretty much cannot be reduced, so at best it could be made ~3 times as fast.

---

In python 2 you can remove the `encode` invocation. That alone saves a few seconds. A set is faster for `in` testing, so that's also an easy fix. Take advantage of `hashlib.sha1`'s `copy` and `update` by noticing the length stays constant and you are at 2x the speed:

```
def getHash(data, h):
    h = h.copy() # "fork" the hash
    h.update(data)
    return h.hexdigest()

def populate(n):
    h = hashlib.sha1("blob " + str(n) + "\0") # shared part of the hash
    for data in product(possible_letters, repeat=n):
        s = getHash(''.join(data), h)[0:7]
        if s in messages:
            print(s,data)
```

On Python 3 you can encode the letters into bytes and avoid `encode` inside the loop, for similar performance.

You might still make it about 1.5x as fast if you replaced the `product` -> `join` algorithm with something faster (`bytearray(n)` and depth first search?), but that's about it.